# Does Changing the Valuye of %esp Remove Values from Stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack

So a command like `subl $4, %esp` would open up a word of local variable space on the stack.  Then `%esp` would point to this value.  However, after a function call, when you restore `%esp` by `movl %ebp, %esp`, this would make `%esp` point above the local variable space you had opened up before.  Then does this space no longer exist on the stack, because `%esp` must always point at the bottom of the stack, and moving the value of `%esp` then removes lower stuff from stack?  Also, after function calls I have seen code `addl $8, %esp`.  Does this just delete the local variable data and the rest of the stack data until the return address, where `$8` is the length from the bottom of stack to the return address?

Forgive me for the strange wording of my question.  I think I might understand these concepts but I am not sure, therefore I simply tried to write what I think and then wait for corrections.

Comment: Yes, logically it removes things from the stack, but physically they are still there in memory until overwritten.

Comment: That is precisely the purpose the stack serves. When you `push` a value onto the stack and then later `pop` the value off the stack, you are doing the same thing. The stack grows lower, so take for example your current stack pointer at 100, you push an `int`, your stack pointer is 96, you pop the `int` and your stack pointer is again 100, but until you overwrite your int, it still exists at 96.

Comment: So basically,  incrementing the stack pointer also removes things from the stack in a less formal way than pop?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function, the ESP restore just remove the function's variables from the stack. From caller you have to remove the parameters given to that function.
I don't know the AT notation but you will understand

```
...
push %eax ; ESP will be decreased by 4
push %ebx ; ESP will be decreased by 4
call fucntion
addl $8, %esp ; restore ESP removing the parameters from stack
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that in assembly we leave all the convenient abstractions of high-level languages behind us. Memory is just bytes. "The stack" is just a piece of memory, with `%esp` somewhere in the middle. And the CPU doesn't really know where the edges of the stack are.

So, when we change `%esp`, we don't change values, because they don't exist to us. We don't change bytes, either, because a change to `%esp` affects just a CPU register and not memory.